# How to pass array and other type of variable to oracle stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to pass one array and one integer variable to a oracle stored procedure from c#.net application. I can pass both parameter as array but can't pass two different type of variable. Is there any solution where I can pass array and any other type of variable together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN keyword to pass the parameters as input.

Check here for more details:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/CreateProcedureAndFunction.html

So your array and the other variable can both have IN and be sent as parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my problem is I can't pass two different type of parameters. If I pass two array, the application works fine but if I pass one array and one int32 (using IN), I got the error :casting error from System.Int32 to System.Array.

Comment: You have to ensure the order in which they are passed matches the order in which they are received in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a delimited string and split it on the DB.

Comment: Thank you Esteban. I will apply that option at the end if I can't solve this problem.